# Two storyboard synchronization

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

I have 2 storyboard animation.

**xaml**

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="hideMe">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:0.1" To="0.0">
                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            </DoubleAnimation>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0:0.1" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="showMe">
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:0.1" To="1.0">
                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            </DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
```

**cs**

```
public void ShowWindow()
{           
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate ()
    {
            (FindResource("showMe") as Storyboard).Begin(this);
    }));
}

public void HideWindow()
{           
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate ()
    {   
            (FindResource("hideMe") as Storyboard).Begin(this);
    }));
}
```

If I run one by one 2 storyboard they will play at the same time.

```
ShowWindow();
HideWindow();
```

How can i wait when first animation ended and after it run the second animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Completed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed?view=netcore-3.1) event of the first `Storyboard` that will run:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="hideMe">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:0.1" To="0.0">
                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            </DoubleAnimation>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0:0.1" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="showMe">
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:0.1" To="1.0">
                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            </DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Code-Behind:

```cs
public void ShowWindow()
{           
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate ()
    {
        (FindResource("showMe") as Storyboard).Begin(this);
    }));
}

private void Storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate ()
    {   
        (FindResource("hideMe") as Storyboard).Begin(this);
    }));
}
```

Note: In my example `showMe` will start first and after it completes `hideMe` will start.